Prisma Client Error when trying to access Dropbox Sign API
I am using a Nest.js API (with ts-rest) to do CRUD operations using Prisma. In a "Contracts" route, I am trying to use the Dropbox Sign API to return some contract templates that I have made. In this route there are no calls to prismaService, however when I query that API route from the front end at runtime, a Prisma Client Error gets thrown:
[Nest] 59585  - 06/19/2024, 5:10:18 PM   ERROR PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `d.NestFactory.create()` invocation in
/workspaces/prime-crm/dist/apps/api/main.js:1:318142

→ 1 (()=>{var __webpack_modules__=[function(s,n,r){"use strict";var a=this&&this.__awaiter||function(s,n,r,a){return new(r||(r=Promise))((function(o,l){function d(s){try{c(a.next(s))}catch(n){l(n)}}function u(s){try{c(a.throw(s))}catch(n){l(n)}}function c(s){var n;s.done?o(s.value):(n=s.value,n instanceof r?n:new r((function(s){s(n)}))).then(d,u)}c((a=a.apply(s,n||[])).next())}))},o=this&&this.__importDefault||function(s){return s&&s.__esModule?s:{default:s}};Object.defineProperty(n,"__esModule",{value:!0});const l=r(1),d=r(2),u=r(3),c=r(6),f=o(r(170)),p=r(12),g=r(171),y=r(172),A=r(4);!function(){a(this,void 0,void 0,(function*(){const s=yield d.NestFactory.create({
      where: {
    +   id: Int
      }
    })

Argument `id` is missing.

What I am confused about is that in this particular route, I am not using Prisma at all for any Create operations, I am just trying to return templates. I have no clue as to why it is getting called. All other routes in the Service are working as intended.
The "contracts/templates" route, and relevant API Contract section:
API contract:
import { ContractPlainType, initContract } from "@ts-rest/core"
import * as DropboxSign from "@dropbox/sign"
const c = initContract()
const contracts = c.router({
  [other routes],
  getTemplates: {
    method: "GET",
    path: "/contracts/templates",
    responses: {
      200: c.type<DropboxSign.TemplateResponse[]>(),
    },
    summary: "Return all HelloSign Templates",
  },
})
export const contract = c.router(contracts)

Contracts Module:
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common"
import { ContractsService } from "./contracts.service"
import { ContractsController } from "./contracts.controller"
import { PrismaService } from "../prisma.service"

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [ContractsController],
  providers: [ContractsService, PrismaService],
  exports: [ContractsService],
})
export class ContractsModule {}

Contracts Controller:
import { Controller } from "@nestjs/common"
import { ContractsService } from "./contracts.service"
import { TsRestHandler, tsRestHandler } from "@ts-rest/nest"
import { contract } from "@crm/rest-api-contract"

@Controller()
export class ContractsController {
  constructor(private readonly contractsService: ContractsService) {}
  
  @TsRestHandler(contract.contracts.getTemplates)
  async getTemplates() {
    return tsRestHandler(contract.contracts.getTemplates, async () => {
      const templates = await this.contractsService.getTemplates()
      // if (!templates) return { status: 200, body: [] }
      return { status: 200, body: templates || [] }
    })
  }
}

Contracts Service:
import * as DropboxSign from "@dropbox/sign"
@Injectable()
export class ContractsService {
  constructor(
    private readonly prisma: PrismaService,
  ) {}

async getTemplates() {
    try {
      const templateApi = new DropboxSign.TemplateApi()
      templateApi.username = process.env.DROPBOX_SIGN_KEY || ""
      const templatesReturn = await templateApi.templateList()
      console.log("TEMPLATES", templatesReturn.body.templates)
      return templatesReturn.body.templates
    } catch (e) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(e)
    }
  }

I have tried removing that route, and putting the logic to access the Dropbox Sign API into another route that DOES call some sort of Prisma CRUD operation, and no issues arise.
I am pretty new to ts-rest and Nest.js so I am having trouble working through the error, any help is much appreciated.
